# Jenkins + Git plugin CheckoutConflictException

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to setup my CI and I created a free style job but it fails on git clone step with this log below. I correctly configured the computer with the ssh keys and I can't find any problem.

```
Using strategy: Default
Fetching changes from 1 remote Git repository
Commencing build of Revision 9560773cf0e8545f98c6700c44fd2f9ae31af904 (origin/master)
Checking out Revision 9560773cf0e8545f98c6700c44fd2f9ae31af904 (origin/master)
FATAL: Could not checkout 9560773cf0e8545f98c6700c44fd2f9ae31af904
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not checkout 9560773cf0e8545f98c6700c44fd2f9ae31af904
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.JGitAPIImpl.checkout(JGitAPIImpl.java:68)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.checkout(GitAPI.java:208)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1261)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.access$1200(GitSCM.java:57)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$4.invoke(GitSCM.java:1220)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$4.invoke(GitSCM.java:1196)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:865)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:838)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1196)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1353)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:683)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:88)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:588)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1567)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:237)
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.CheckoutConflictException: Checkout conflict with     files:
Heatmaps.framework/Headers/Heatmaps.h
Heatmaps.framework/Resources/Info.plist
Heatmaps.framework/Versions/Current/Headers
Heatmaps.framework/Versions/Current/Headers/Heatmaps.h
Heatmaps.framework/Versions/Current/Heatmaps
Heatmaps.framework/Versions/Current/Resources
Heatmaps.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/Info.plist
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CheckoutCommand.call(CheckoutCommand.java:244)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.JGitAPIImpl.checkout(JGitAPIImpl.java:64)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.CheckoutConflictException: Checkout conflict with files:
Heatmaps.framework/Headers/Heatmaps.h
Heatmaps.framework/Resources/Info.plist
Heatmaps.framework/Versions/Current/Headers
Heatmaps.framework/Versions/Current/Headers/Heatmaps.h
Heatmaps.framework/Versions/Current/Heatmaps
Heatmaps.framework/Versions/Current/Resources
Heatmaps.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/Info.plist
    at org.eclipse.jgit.dircache.DirCacheCheckout.doCheckout(DirCacheCheckout.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.dircache.DirCacheCheckout.checkout(DirCacheCheckout.java:391)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CheckoutCommand.call(CheckoutCommand.java:240)
    ... 17 more
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was getting this error when I installed the new Jenkins 1.505 and using git client plugin 1.0.4. You can downgrade the plugin to 1.0.3 and it might work. I was not really using the git client plugin so removed it in my case

Comment: Thnks man! Now I see they had already created a bug in JIRA https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-17198

Comment: If you don't have a downgrade option you can use this site to download old versions of the git plugin: http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/git-client/

Comment: how to downgrade? Particularly, how to do that on a Windows Jenkins machine?

Comment: Go to http://localhost:8080/pluginManager/installed whereever ur jenkins is installed. uninstall, if there is no downgrade option. (uncheck the plugins usage in the job u might have defined), restart jenkins, download the old .hpi file containing the plugin and use the jenkins ui or manually to upload a new plugin https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugins#Plugins-Howtoinstallplugins

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. They have released an update that corrects that error, so you only have to update Jenkins Git Client to 1.0.5. Now it's working.

Answer (score 4):

I just ran into the same issue and wanted to provide an alternative solution:

In the 1.0.4 version info on [the plugin's page](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Client+Plugin) you can read:

> use JGit implementation in GitAPI for all supported methods, until org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.Git.useCLI is set

which seems to be the cause of our problems. But it says that one can work around it by setting `org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.Git.useCLI` to true.
So just add `-Dorg.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.Git.useCLI=true` to your start script.

On Debian (when using the apt-get version), it's sufficient to update `JAVA_ARGS` in `/etc/default/jenkins` (as described [here](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-17204))

Comment: Where is JAVA_ARGS being set on a Windows machine?

Comment: @AlbertCheng You can either set it system-wide (or for the current user): http://www.nextofwindows.com/how-to-addedit-environment-variables-in-windows-7/
or if you start jenkins using a `.bat` script, you could set it locally:
http://ss64.com/nt/set.html

I don't have a windows installation at hand so I can't try it out myself but if you run into trouble just post it :)

Comment: I guess I figured them out, just modify both master and slave's configuration xml file get this fixed. Not easy, not easy!